# Is the only way to get the piece of heart in the restaurant to break the chandelier?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Is it possible to get the piece of heart without breaking the custom-made chandelier in the Lumpy Pumpkin at Pumpkin Landing in *Skyward Sword*?

> I already broke it and have to make deliveries to make up for it. Also: totally worth everyone's reaction. ;p

Comment: @JeffMercado I don't know what that item is, I'm not that far :p .

Comment: It's the item you get in the first dungeon, but I won't spoil it for you any further.  :)

Comment: As far as I know, yes.  The Dungeon 1 item can't collect heart container pieces (it would bypass most of the heart piece puzzles; where is the fun in that?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. **The only way to get the piece of heart in *The Lumpy Pumpkin* is to knock down the chandelier.** There aren't any items that will retrieve it for you. I'm pretty sure you're *supposed* to knock it down, so you can work to pay off your debt:

> You get a piece of heart when the owner is through with you.

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less what I was going to post. The Ⓑ button is locked in there, so rolling and knocking down the chandelier is the only option.

Comment: I hope this isn't a spoiler, but you get another piece of heart for paying off the debt.

Comment: Gah, I was going to post this, but wanted to see what the reward for paying it off was, so I could include that. :P

Answer (score -5):

No, if the beetle will work, you can use it and I would use it for the rupees 2.

Comment: -1: Wrong on two counts: you can't use items inside the building, and the Beetle can't pick up Heart Pieces.